# Let $M=\mathbb{C}^3$ be the $\mathbb{C}[x]-$module given by the matrix, prove that $M$ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $M=\mathbb{C}^3$ be the $\mathbb{C}[x]-$module given by the matrix
>
> $$
> A=
> \begin{bmatrix}
>     0       & 0 & 1 \\
>     1       & 0 & 0 \\
>     0      & 1 & 0 
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>
> Prove that $M$ is cyclic and write $M$ as the direct sum of three nonzero submodules.

I have a question here: if $M=\mathbb{C}^3$, why is $M$ cyclic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: suppose the base is $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$, $(A(e_1)=e_2,A(e_2)=e_3,A(e_3)=e_1)$ is a basis so $M$ is cyclic.

The characteristic polynomial of $M$ is $X^3-1$ which has 3 distinct roots. The vector spaced associated to each root is a non zero submodule.

Comment: also why does $X^3-1$ have 3 distinct roots? Will $1$ be the only root?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $x^3-1$, and only has one root $1$. What do you mean by "the vector spaced associated to each root"?